# "am + having" in one sentence

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous

In the [*Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/current) there is an example:

> The Director **is currently having** talks in the US.

Based on this example can I write:

> **Currently**, I **am having** two common projects with Mr "A" and Mr "B".

Comment: Note that, in both cases, "currently" is redundant, since the use of the present progressive without stating a time already implies that the action is occurring now.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "am having" sometimes implies future time.  E.g., "my wisdom teeth hurt, so I'm having them removed."  That would usually be understood to say they they *will* be removed, not that they are *currently* being removed.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Good point: I think I oversimplified the reasoning. But "currently" still feels redundant in both cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Have* is one of the verbs that can be stative or active depending on their meaning.

- If I have a car or a house or a project, then I am trying to say that they belong to me, in which case *have* expresses possession and is stative.
- Here are examples of active meanings: *having a shower* means taking one, *having breakfast* means eating, *having beer* means drinking and *having talks* means talking or negotiating.

So in your first sentence, *have* is active and is used in the continuous tense correctly. In the second case, however, you **have** two projects (stative), and you **are working on** two projects (active).

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically, yes, but perhaps "having" is not the best verb here. You might want to choose a more "active" word:

Would "am working on" or even "am doing" be an option for you?